# Laravel 5.4: how to pass model object to controller via middleware?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am creating an app in Laravel 5.4, where I have a middleware `ValidateBooking` and then a controller called with a URL like `/booking/6/car`, which lists all the cars assigned to that booking.

In the `ValidateBooking` middleware I am validating the booking id `6` in the above URL by using the `Booking::find(6)` Eloquent function. But what I want is, if the Booking exists then pass that object to the controller, so I do not fetch it again in the controller. I don't want to query the database twice for the same thing.

I tried a few methods to merge the model object with `$request` in the middleware, but was not able to access it in the controller properly.

My middleware code is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware\Booking;

use Closure;
use App\Booking\Booking;

class ValidateBooking
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $booking = Booking::find($request->booking_id);
        if (!$booking) {
            return redirect(route('booking.show', $request->booking_id));
        }
        $request->attributes->add(['bookingInstance' => $booking]);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And then fetching it in the Controller like:

`$request->get('bookingInstance')`

It works if I pass any string value or something, but not for an object? Please advise what could be the best way for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think you want to look at is [Explicit Route Model bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding).

If you add an explicit binding to the `RouteServiceProvider`, you can then access that parameter in your middleware and in your controller.

```
// app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    Route::model('booking', \App\Booking\Booking::class);
}


// routes/web.php

Route::get('/booking/{booking}/car', 'BookingController@car')->middleware('booking.validate');


// app/Http/Middleware/ValidateBooking.php

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $booking = $request->booking;

    // ...

    return $next($request);
}


// app/Http/Controllers/BookingController.php

public function car(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->booking);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good. What if instead middleware i just bind the model with route qnd if it didn't find any booking then i can handle the 404 to redirect it to where i need, will that work or i will need a middle ware here. I simply want to validate if thta booking is present else give error. Please advise your thoughts?

Comment: I usually use `findOrFail($id)` in my controller. I'm not sure what happens if Laravel can't find a route binding. It may throw a 404 for you. Test it out.

Answer (score 5):

You just be able to use the `merge()` function on the request object.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $booking = Booking::find($request->booking_id);
    if (!$booking) {
        return redirect(route('booking.show', $request->booking_id));
    }
    $request->merge(['bookingInstance' => $booking]);
    return $next($request);
}
```

Apart from using `$request->merge()` which is proven to work, simply adding the model object to the request with the following also helps you access the model in the controller:

```
$request->booking = $booking;
```

The only thing to be aware of is just simply ensuring that there was never a parameter called booking so as not to override it.

Comment: Indeed, using merge works. @Prashant you should consider this.

Comment: @Chris I tried this, but the problem is I am trying to access the request in the constructor of the controller Class, and in my case constructor of Controller is called before the middleware handle() , how should I fix this?

Comment: Can you add the code for your controller to the question. Why do you need it in the constructor? Can't you just wait and take the action in the function that is called to handle the request after the Middleware has run?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do. I had this problem once.

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $booking = Booking::find($request->booking_id);
    if (!$booking) {
        return redirect(route('booking.show', $request->booking_id));
    }
    sesion()->put('bookingInstance', $booking);
    return $next($request);
}
```

This is a simple.